# categorize by hash value

Tags: ruby, arrays, select, hash, reduce

I have an array of hashes with values like:

```
by_person = [{ :person => "Jane Smith", :filenames => ["Report.pdf", "File2.pdf"]}, {:person => "John Doe", :filenames => ["Report.pdf] }]
```

I would like to end up with another array of hashes (`by_file`) that has each unique value from the filenames key as a key in the `by_file` array:

```
by_file = [{ :filename => "Report.pdf", :people => ["Jane Smith", "John Doe"] }, { :filename => "File2.pdf", :people => [Jane Smith] }]
```

I have tried:

```
by_file = []

by_person.each do |person|
  person[:filenames].each do |file|
    unless by_file.include?(file)
      # list people that are included in file
      by_person_each_file = by_person.select{|person| person[:filenames].include?(file)}
      by_person_each_file.each do |person|
        by_file << {
          :file => file,
          :people => person[:person]
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

as well as:

```
by_file.map(&:to_a).reduce({}) {|h,(k,v)| (h[k] ||= []) << v; h}
```

Any feedback is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `by_file.include? file` is never going to work. You can't test an array of hashes against a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't seem too tricky, but the way you're compiling it isn't very efficient:

```
by_person = [{ :person => "Jane Smith", :filenames => ["Report.pdf", "File2.pdf"]}, {:person => "John Doe", :filenames => ["Report.pdf"] }]

by_file = by_person.each_with_object({ }) do |entry, index|
  entry[:filenames].each do |filename|
    set = index[filename] ||= [ ]
    set << entry[:person]
  end
end.collect do |filename, people|
  {
    filename: filename,
    people: people
  }
end

puts by_file.inspect
# => [{:filename=>"Report.pdf", :people=>["Jane Smith", "John Doe"]}, {:filename=>"File2.pdf", :people=>["Jane Smith"]}]
```

This makes use of a hash to group the people by filename, essentially inverting your structure, and then converts that into the final format in a second pass. This is more efficient than working with the final format during compilation as that's not indexed and requires an expensive linear search to find the correct container to insert into.

An alternate method is to create a default hash constructor that makes the structure you're looking for:

```
by_file_hash = Hash.new do |h,k|
  h[k] = {
    filename: k,
    people: [ ]
  }
end

by_person.each do |entry|
  entry[:filenames].each do |filename|
    by_file_hash[filename][:people] << entry[:person]
  end
end

by_file = by_file_hash.values

puts by_file.inspect
# => [{:filename=>"Report.pdf", :people=>["Jane Smith", "John Doe"]}, {:filename=>"File2.pdf", :people=>["Jane Smith"]}]
```

This may or may not be easier to understand.

Comment: `Hash.new { .. }` I like too much.. +1

Comment: The second way is especially nice, and reads very well. You could shorten it with `each_with_object` or `tap`--as you no doubt considered--but that would make it awfully dense. Best as is, imo.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, having a customized Hash as an argument to `each_with_object` gets to be a bit overwhelming if the definition isn't trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it.

**Code**

```
def convert(by_person)
  by_person.each_with_object({}) do |hf,hp|
    hf[:filenames].each do |fname|
      hp.update({ fname=>[hf[:person]] }) { |_,oh,nh| oh+nh }
    end    
  end.map { |fname,people| { :filename => fname, :people=>people } }
end
```

**Example**

```
by_person = [{:person=>"Jane Smith", :filenames=>["Report.pdf", "File2.pdf"]},
             {:person=>"John Doe",   :filenames=>["Report.pdf"]}]

convert(by_person)
  #=> [{:filename=>"Report.pdf", :people=>["Jane Smith", "John Doe"]},
  #    {:filename=>"File2.pdf",  :people=>["Jane Smith"]}]
```

**Explanation**

For `by_person` in the example:

```
enum1 = by_person.each_with_object({})
  #=>[{:person=>"Jane Smith", :filenames=>["Report.pdf", "File2.pdf"]},
      {:person=>"John Doe", :filenames=>["Report.pdf"]}]:each_with_object({})>
```

Let's see what values the enumerator `enum` will pass into the block:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[{:person=>"Jane Smith", :filenames=>["Report.pdf", "File2.pdf"]}, {}], 
  #    [{:person=>"John Doe", :filenames=>["Report.pdf"]}, {}]]
```

As will be shown below, the empty hash in the first element of the enumerator will no longer be empty with the second element is passed into the block.

The first element is assigned to the block variables as follows (I've indented to indicate the block level):

```
  hf = {:person=>"Jane Smith", :filenames=>["Report.pdf", "File2.pdf"]}
  hp = {}

  enum2 = hf[:filenames].each
    #=> #<Enumerator: ["Report.pdf", "File2.pdf"]:each>
  enum2.to_a
    #=> ["Report.pdf", "File2.pdf"]
```

`"Report.pdf"` is passed to the inner block, assigned to the block variable:

```
  fname = "Report.pdf"
```

and

```
  hp.update({ "Report.pdf"=>["Jane Smith"] }) { |_,oh,nh| oh+nh }
    #=> {"Report.pdf"=>["Jane Smith"]}
```

is executed, returning the updated value of `hp`.

Here the block for [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `Hash#merge!`) is not consulted. It is only needed when the hash `hp` and the merging hash (here `{ fname=>["Jane Smith"] }`) have one or more common keys. For each common key, the key and the corresponding values from the two hashes are passed to the block.  This is elaborated below.

Next, `enum2` passes `"File2.pdf"` into the block and assigns it to the block variable:

```
  fname = "File2.pdf"
```

and executes

```
  hp.update({ "File2.pdf"=>["Jane Smith"] }) { |_,oh,nh| oh+nh }
    #=> {"Report.pdf"=>["Jane Smith"], "File2.pdf"=>["Jane Smith"]}
```

which returns the updated value of `hp`.  Again, `update`'s block was not consulted.  We're now finished with Jane, so `enum1` next passes its second and last value into the block and assigns the block variables as follows:

```
hf = {:person=>"John Doe", :filenames=>["Report.pdf"]}
hp = {"Report.pdf"=>["Jane Smith"], "File2.pdf"=>["Jane Smith"]}
```

Note that `hp` has now been updated. We then have:

```
  enum2 = hf[:filenames].each
    #=> #<Enumerator: ["Report.pdf"]:each>
  enum2.to_a
    #=> ["Report.pdf"]
```

`enum2` assigns

```
  fname = "Report.pdf"
```

and executes:

```
  hp.update({ "Report.pdf"=>["John Doe"] }) { |_,oh,nv| oh+nv }
    #=> {"Report.pdf"=>["Jane Smith", "John Doe"], "File2.pdf"=>["Jane Smith"]}
```

In making this `update`, `hp` and the hash being merged both have the key `"Report.pdf"`. The following values are therefore passed to the block variables `|k,ov,nv|`:

```
  k  = "Report.pdf"
  oh = ["Jane Smith"] 
  nh = ["John Doe"]
```

We don't need the key, so I've replaced it with an underscore. The block returns

```
["Jane Smith"]+["John Doe"] #=> ["Jane Smith", "John Doe"]
```

which becomes the new value for the key `"Report.pdf"`.

Before turning to the final step, I'd like to suggest that you consider stopping here. That is, rather than constructing an array of hashes, one for each file, just leave it as a hash with the files as keys and arrays of persons the values:

```
{ "Report.pdf"=>["Jane Smith", "John Doe"], "File2.pdf"=>["Jane Smith"] }
```

The final step is straightforward:

```
hp.map { |fname,people| { :filename => fname, :people=>people } }
  #=> [{ :filename=>"Report.pdf", :people=>["Jane Smith", "John Doe"] },
  #    { :filename=>"File2.pdf", :people=>["Jane Smith"] }]
```